# CGEventTap, CGEvent & NSEvent Memory Leak

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm having a tough time releasing a CGEvent once I convert it to NSEvent (which I need). I'm doing this using a CGEventTap.
From the documentation it states

> Returns: An autoreleased NSEvent object that is equivalent to cgEvent
>
> The returned object retains the CGEventRef object (cgEvent) until it (the Objective-C object) is freed—it then releases the CGEventRef object. If no Cocoa event corresponds to the CGEventRef object, this method returns nil.

So I have written some code to convert to NSEvent and then immediately set the NSEvent to nil (as a test). Even after setting it to nil, either NSEvent or the CGEvent with it are not released and my memory keeps going up with every mouse move. I'm not entirely sure why. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here.

Here's the code.

```
func eventCallBack(proxy: CGEventTapProxy, type: CGEventType, var event: CGEvent, refcon: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>? {
    
    //this line is what causes the memory leak
    if var e: NSEvent? = NSEvent(CGEvent: event) { 
       e = nil //according to docs, this should decrease reference count to event
    }

    return Unmanaged.passUnretained(event!)
}
```

Comment: Maybe you're missing an autorelease pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Willeke commented, an `autoreleasepool` fixed the memory leak for me.

Swift should be automatically cleaning up the NSEvents for you, so setting `e` to nil shouldn't be necessary inside the autoreleasepool.

Here's what worked for me:

```
func eventCallBack(proxy: CGEventTapProxy, type: CGEventType, var event: CGEvent, refcon: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>? {

  autoreleasepool{ 
    var e: NSEvent? = NSEvent(CGEvent: event)
    // code using e
  }

  return Unmanaged.passUnretained(event)
}
```